# how to get all comboboxes value on form submission using PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to get all combo boxes' values, but when I click on submit button I only get the last combo box's value. Also, how do I get the value of label? Here's how I generate the list of combo boxes:

```
while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($reusult))
{

  echo"

  <div class=\"form-group row\">
  <label  type=\"hidden\"  for=\"exampleInputEmail2\" class=\"col-md-3\" id=\"mode\" name=\"mode\" 
  value="; echo $i['moduleCode'];echo " > ";

  echo $i['moduleName'];

  echo "
  </label>

  <div class=\"col-md-4\">";

  addDropDownRequired('modules','modules','descr','id','moduledropdownperm',false);

  echo "
  </div>
  </div>";
}
}
```

Comment: The dropdown box only returns selected value. That is the purpose of combo box. If you want to get all values you should try different method.

Comment: i mean if i have multiple combo boxes with same name than how will get the values of each combo box

Comment: name is as `name="yourname[]"` then you will receive in PHP as an array (`<?php $data = $_POST['yourname']; ?>`). But It only used in Checkboxes. Try it.

Comment: Yes it works thankyou so much,cany you please tell me one thing more

Comment: how i will get the value of label i search alot but did nt find any thing,i dont want to hide it

Comment: get the value of label from PHP?

Comment: yes i want to get value of label after submit button

Comment: Can't do one thing put the value of Label in hidden input Like `<label>username</label>< input type="hidden" value="myLabel">` then get it from PHP like `$_POST['myLabel']`

Comment: Yes it works,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name is as `name="yourname[]"` then you will receive in PHP as an array (`<?php $data = $_POST['yourname']; ?>`). But It only used in Checkboxes. Try it